# Why can't we have automatically deduced return types?

Tags: c++, c++11

Recently I was working a friend who wanted to make C++ more Haskell-y, and we wanted a function that's basically like this:

```
auto sum(auto a, auto b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Apparently I can't use auto as a parameter type, so I changed it to this:

```
template<class A, class B>
auto sum(A a, B b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

But that doesn't work either. What we eventually realized we need this:

```
template<class A, class B>
auto sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

So my question is, what's the point? Isn't `decltype` just repeating information, since the compiler can just look at the return statement?

I considered that maybe it's needed so we can just include a header file:

```
template<class A, class B>
auto sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b);
```

... but we can't use templates like that anyway.

The other thing I considered was that it might be easier for the compiler, but it seems like it would actually be harder.

Case 1: With `decltype`

- Figure out the type of the `decltype` statement
- Figure out the types of any return values
- See if they match

Case 2: Without `decltype`

- Figure out the types of any return values
- See if they match

So with those things in mind, what's the point of the trailing return type with `decltype`?

Comment: I think that's because all the type information of the function must be known just from the declaration (that doesn't include the function body), without needing to go through the definition.

Comment: I believe that question would be better worded as "Why do we need trailing return types?" They are just one use-case for `decltype` and the question doesn't touch on any of the others.

Comment: @pmr `decltype` can be used without the trailing return syntax. It's less convenient in the above case (requires use of `std::declval`) but really the two features are orthogonal.

Comment: @LucDanton Right, so it should rather be "Why can't we have automatically deduced return types?"

Comment: @Brendan: Simple answer is it *could*, but the committee either explicitly or implicitly concluded it wasn't worth the effort. C++ is an overly-complex language already, and adding rules to allow this is possible but adds even more complexity. That is, I agree being able to say `auto foo(auto x, auto y) { return x + y;}`  would be nice, and it's certainly possible, but it's just as doable with the extra syntax, just more annoying; the annoyance is easier to deal with than new rules. That said, it is *extremely* unfortunate they didn't elaborate on deducing return types for things like lambdas.

Comment: You could also `#define func(sig) auto sig -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { return __VA_ARGS__; }` and then say `template<class A, class B> func(sum(A a, B b), a + b)`, but that would be a bit excessive.

Comment: I know it's a lot later now, but GCC 4.8.0 has support for this with the `-std=c++1y` option. It's being proposed right now.

Comment: Even more later, return type deduction is now part of the standard.

Comment: Even later than that, use of `auto` as a parameter type is part of the Concepts TS, and may eventually be merged into the core language yet still later.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Well - time passed since the original question was asked and the answer now is that you can!

<sub>Yes, it is true that the question is tagged C++11 - with which you still cannot do what the OP is asking for. But it's worthwhile to show what is doable with C++14 and later.</sub>

**Since C++14 this is valid:**

```
template<class A, class B>
auto sum(A a, B b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

**And since C++20 this is also valid:**

```
auto sum(auto a, auto b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

---

The following is the *C++11 answer*, kept here for historical reasons, with some comments from the future *(C++14 and later)*:

What if we have the following:

```
template<class A, class B, class C>
auto sum(A a, B b, C c) {
   if (rand () == 0) return a + b;

   // do something else...

    return a + c;
}
```

.. where `a + b` and `a + c` expressions yield different type of results.
What should compiler decide to put as a return type for that function and why?
This case is already covered by C++11 lambdas which allow to omit the return type as long as `return` statements can be deduced to the same type (NB standard quote needed, some sources claim only one return expression is allowed and that this is a gcc glitch).

---

<sub>A note from the future (C++14 and on): the example above is still not valid, you may only have a single possible return type. However if there are different return types but the actual return type can be deduced at compile type, then we have two different functions, which is valid. The following for example is valid since C++17:</sub>

```
template<class A, class B, class C>
auto sum(A a, B b, C c) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<A, B>) return a + b;
    else return a + c;
}

int main() {
    auto a1 = sum(1, 2l, 3.5); // 4.5
    auto a2 = sum(1, 2, 3.5); // 3
}
```

---

<sub>Back to the original *C++11 answer*, explaining why the requested syntax is not supported:</sub>

A technical reason is that C++ allows the definition and declaration to be separate.

```
template<class A, class B>
auto sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b);

template<class A, class B>
auto sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
}
```

The definition of the template *could* be in the header. Or it could be in another file, so that you don't have to wade through pages and pages of function definitions when looking through an interface.

C++ has to account for all possibilities. Restricting trailing return types to just function definitions means that you can't do something as simple as this:

```
template<class A, class B>
class Foo
{
  auto sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b);
}

template<class A, class B>
auto Foo<A, B>::sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
}
```

<sub>A note from the future (C++14 and on): you still cannot have a declaration with `auto` return type, if the definition is not available when the compiler sees the call.</sub>

Comment: The function wouldn't compile anyway if the return statements return different things.

Comment: @BrendanLong: Not necessarily. There can be implicit conversion going on. But without explicit type compiler won't know what to convert and why.

Comment: Pretty much any function with multiple returns comes to mind. I was thinking about recursion first, but that is even easier.

Comment: Technically, this is a solved problem. Lambdas allow you to omit the return type, so long as the `decltype` of all of the `return` statements is the same. So C++11 already has language that would solve this problem; compilers will report an error in a lambda where the `return`s are inconsistent. Therefore, this alone is not a valid reason for the spec to require trailing return types on named functions.

Comment: True, lambdas determine return type and fail if you try to return different things. Perhaps there is nothing that actually stands on the way of throwing this level of intelligence to compilers... except that maybe function declarations may play a significant part in SFINATE, and not specifying the type explicitly may not work out well... I don't know.

Comment: @NicolBolas If I'm not mistaken you cant call a lambda recursively but you can a normal function. Resolving this would possibly require a lot of effort for the compiler. But maybe I'm wrong and it is really that simple.

Comment: @pmr: Recursion is a _very_ good point. You should make that an answer ;)

Comment: Perhaps we should combine our answers together and make a community wiki.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I also added an answer. I can merge it into yours, if you want.

Comment: Where does the standard say this about lambdas with multiple returns being allowed to omit the return type? All I can find in the FDIS is 5.1.2/4, which says that if the return type is omitted and the entire lambda consists of a single return statement, returning an expression, then that is the return type, otherwise the return type is `void`. Is this a big change between the FDIS and the standard, or a non-standard feature of some compiler (perhaps MSVC), or just something I've missed?

Comment: @SteveJessop I was confused at that as well and that's why I added the "need for quotation".

Answer (score 8):

> but we can't use templates like that anyway.

First, trailing return types aren't purely a template thing. They work for all functions. Secondly, says who? This is perfectly legal code:

```
template<class A, class B>
auto sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b);

template<class A, class B>
auto sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
}
```

The definition of the template *could* be in the header. Or it could be in another file, so that you don't have to wade through pages and pages of function definitions when looking through an interface.

C++ has to account for all possibilities. Restricting trailing return types to just function definitions means that you can't do something as simple as this:

```
template<class A, class B>
class Foo
{
  auto sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b);
}

template<class A, class B>
auto Foo<A, B>::sum(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
}
```

And this is fairly common for many programmers. There's nothing wrong with wanting to code this way.

The only reason lambdas get away without the return type is because they have to have a function body defined with the definition. If you restricted trailing return types to only those functions where the definition was available, you wouldn't be able to use either of the above cases.

Comment: In theory though it is possible to implement such a feature, but only for cases where function yields one and only one type of result. And ignore function if matching definition is not found... But seems like way to much intelligence for a vague feature...

Comment: @VladLazarenko: In theory nothing; Lambdas do it right now. You don't have to specify a return type unless the different types of the return values in the lambda disagree. The specification _could_ have allowed it, but it would also have meant disallowing forward declarations of the function.

Comment: Definitely a good point. I wish they had just required this when you *actually use* a forward declaration. :\

Answer (score 5):

There is no technical reason why it is not possible. The main reason they haven't is because the C++ language moves very slowly and it takes a very long time for features to be added.

You can *nearly* get the nice syntax you want with lambdas (but you can't have templacised arguments in lambdas, again for no good reason).

```
auto foo = [](int a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
};
```

Yes, there are some cases where the return type could not be automatically deduced. Just like in a lambda, it could simply be a requirement to declare the return type yourself in those ambiguous cases.

At the moment, the restrictions are just so arbitrary as to be quite frustrating. Also see the removal of concepts for added frustration.

Comment: You can't overload the function either, using this.

Answer (score 0):

In a [blog post](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/11/having-it-all-pythy-syntax/) from Dave Abrahams, he discusses a proposal for having this function syntax:

```
[]min(x, y)
{ return x < y ? x : y }
```

This is based off of possible proposal for polymorphic lambdas. He has also started work [here](https://github.com/dabrahams/clang) on updating clang to support this syntax.